# Why the date time is changing to 0001-01-01 00:00:00 after updating to the current date time now in the constructor?

Tags: c#, wpf

The mainwindow.xaml.cs code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace wpfMultiThreadListViewUpdate
{
    public class ProcessesInfo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public long MemoryUsage { get; set; }
        public List<ProcessesInfo> SubProcesses { get; set; } = new List<ProcessesInfo>();
        public DateTime ProcessDateTime { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Dictionary<int, ProcessesInfo> processDictionary = new Dictionary<int, ProcessesInfo>();
        Process[] processes;

        // New property for selected process
        public ProcessesInfo SelectedProcess { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
            processes = Process.GetProcesses();

            showInformation(processes.Length, lstvw);

            System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
            timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1).TotalMilliseconds;
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateProcessList();
        }

        private void searchBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void UpdateProcessList()
        {
            // New list to hold the updated process information
            List<ProcessesInfo> updatedProcessList = new List<ProcessesInfo>();

            processes = Process.GetProcesses();

            // Check for killed processes and update the status
            foreach (var processInfo in processDictionary.Values.ToList())
            {
                ProcessesInfo updatedProcess = new ProcessesInfo
                {
                    Name = processInfo.Name,
                    Id = processInfo.Id,
                    MemoryUsage = processInfo.MemoryUsage,
                    SubProcesses = processInfo.SubProcesses
                };

                if (processes.All(p => p.Id != processInfo.Id))
                {
                    updatedProcess.Status = "Killed";
                }
                else
                {
                    updatedProcess.Status = "Opened";
                }

                updatedProcessList.Add(updatedProcess);
            }

            // Check for new processes and add them to the dictionary
            foreach (var process in processes)
            {
                if (!processDictionary.ContainsKey(process.Id))
                {
                    processDictionary.Add(process.Id, new ProcessesInfo
                    {
                        Name = process.ProcessName,
                        Id = process.Id,
                        Status = "Opened",
                        MemoryUsage = process.WorkingSet64 / 1024,
                    });

                    updatedProcessList.Add(processDictionary[process.Id]);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Update memory usage for existing processes
                    processDictionary[process.Id].MemoryUsage = process.WorkingSet64 / 1024;
                    updatedProcessList.Add(processDictionary[process.Id]);

                    // Check if the process status has changed
                    if (processDictionary[process.Id].Status != "Killed" && processDictionary[process.Id].Status != "Opened")
                    {
                        processDictionary[process.Id].Status = "Opened";
                    }
                }
            }

            // Update the ListView with the latest process information
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate ()
            {
                // Replace the entire data source with the updated list
                lstvw.ItemsSource = updatedProcessList;

                // Set the selected item to the previous selection if it still exists
                if (SelectedProcess != null && updatedProcessList.IndexOf(SelectedProcess) >= 0)
                {
                    lstvw.SelectedItem = SelectedProcess;
                }
            }));
        }

        private void showInformation(int numberToGet, ListView listvw)
        {
            List<ProcessesInfo> information = getInfo(numberToGet);
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate ()
            {
                foreach (var processInfo in information)
                {
                    // Set the ProcessDateTime property for each process
                    processInfo.ProcessDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                }

                lstvw.ItemsSource = information;
            }));
        }

        private List<ProcessesInfo> getInfo(int numberToGet)
        {
            List<ProcessesInfo> info = new List<ProcessesInfo>();

            for (int i = 0; i < numberToGet; i++)
            {
                info.Add(new ProcessesInfo()
                {
                    Name = processes[i].ProcessName,
                    Status = "Opened",
                    Id = processes[i].Id,
                    ProcessDateTime = DateTime.Now // Initialize ProcessDateTime here
                });
            }

            return info;
        }

        private void expandButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Handle sub-process expand button click here
            ToggleButton button = (ToggleButton)sender;
            ListViewItem listViewItem = FindVisualParent<ListViewItem>(button);
            ProcessesInfo selectedProcess = (ProcessesInfo)listViewItem.DataContext;

            if (button.IsChecked == true)
            {
                // Sub-processes are expanded
                foreach (var subProcess in selectedProcess.SubProcesses)
                {
                    processDictionary.Add(subProcess.Id, subProcess);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Sub-processes are collapsed
                foreach (var subProcess in selectedProcess.SubProcesses)
                {
                    processDictionary.Remove(subProcess.Id);
                }
            }

            UpdateProcessList();
        }

        private static T FindVisualParent<T>(UIElement element) where T : UIElement
        {
            UIElement parent = element;
            while (parent != null)
            {
                if (parent is T correctlyTyped)
                {
                    return correctlyTyped;
                }
                parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent) as UIElement;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

when running the application first time for a second all the processes show i the date time column the current date time but then after a second all the date time for all processes show 0001-01-01   00:00:00

why it's changing to 0001-01-01   00:00:00 and how to fix it so it will keep the current date time now?

Comment: What does `Timer_Elapsed` do?

Comment: @NineBerry edited my question with the full code of the mainwindow.xaml.cs showing much better to understand what it does.  it's a bit long but everything is connected and it's showing where the time part is coming.

Comment: You don't set the date/time in updatedProcessList. You seem to have forgotten it there. Just add it there as well.

Comment: @NineBerry but then it will keep updating the datetime nonstop and i want when running the application to display the datetime.now once and then keep it static not changing for all the processes.  the problem is that it's showing the current datetime now and then after a second change to 0001-01-01 00:00:00

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to copy the property when creating a new `ProcessesInfo` object.

```
// Check for killed processes and update the status
foreach (var processInfo in processDictionary.Values.ToList())
{
    ProcessesInfo updatedProcess = new ProcessesInfo
    {
        Name = processInfo.Name,
        Id = processInfo.Id,

        // --------------------------
        // This is missing
        // --------------------------
        ProcessDateTime = processInfo.ProcessDateTime, 

        MemoryUsage = processInfo.MemoryUsage,
        SubProcesses = processInfo.SubProcesses,
    };

    if (processes.All(p => p.Id != processInfo.Id))
    {
        updatedProcess.Status = "Killed";
    }
    else
    {
        updatedProcess.Status = "Opened";
    }

    updatedProcessList.Add(updatedProcess);
}
```